# Is it necessary to use "the" multiple times?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, conjunction-reduction

It seems that the question has eventually become a series of questions....

---

An example goes as:

> **The** 1st and **(the)** 2nd paragraphs of the article are extremely long.

Another example:

> What are **the** situation, **(the)** task and **(the)** result of your story?

Is it necessary to use *the* in *()*?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Generally, repeating the word "the" before items in a list is not necessary. Think of "the" as being distributed across all the elements.

However, there are some exceptions.

> The first paragraph, which is the funniest paragraph of the article, and **the** second paragraph are extremely long.

Here, the "the" is necessary because you've entered and exited a dependent clause, which the "the" cannot distribute across.

Generally, if it might be confusing to a reader or listener, include the word "the". Similarly, if it would be distracting, omit it.

Comment: I agree that in the first example, _the first and (the) second paragraphs are extremely long_, _the_ is not needed the second time. This is because _first_ and _second_ are adjectives modifying a common plural noun (_paragraphs_). In the last example in the question, _What are the situation, (the) task and (the) result of your story_, all the articles are needed since we are talking about separate coordinate nouns. However, if the coordinate nouns made up a single idea, we would not need an article for each of the nouns.

Comment: @Tragicomic I think the answer will be more complete with your comment. XD