# Articles in a list

Tags: articles

> I saw a bear, a lion and a donkey.

Is the usage of the article *a* necessary before each word in a list like this?

> Biggs set out Monday morning for one of his usual hiking and
>   gold-panning trips near Whiskey Flats when he came across a mother
>   bear, yearling, and cub sitting on a stream bank.

Why is there no article before *cub*?

Comment: I think the second sentence needs one or two more articles (depending on whether the mother was the yearling, or there were three bears).

Comment: Related: [Is it necessary to use “the” multiple times?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/is-it-necessary-to-use-the-multiple-times)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it isn't necessary for an article to appear each time.  However, the two sentence structures have different connotations.

> I saw a bear, a lion and a donkey.

connotes that, at various times, you saw a bear, a lion, and a donkey.

> I saw a bear, lion and donkey.

connotes that you saw a bear, lion, and donkey together in a group.

This connotation isn't inescapable, but it would be the default understanding.

There is no article before *yearling* or *cub* in your example because the writer intends to describe the three as appearing together.  The construction also draws on an established understanding of a mother bear, yearling and cub being an expected family unit for bears to be traveling in; the entire construction is, in a partial sense, being treated as a single collective entity.

Comment: I wonder if that's an American English thing. British English would tend to add the indefinite article to all of them, and not make the same/different time connotation (which needs to be stated explicitly if it's important and not apparent from the context).

Comment: @Andrew Leach: I'm UK too, but I incline towards the distinction chaos makes here. Not that it's *definitive* (though I doubt it is to Americans either), but I certainly wouldn't expect *"Across the street we saw a man, a woman, and a child"* in normal speech.

Comment: Hmm. In that case, it's a bit more nuanced. One might expect *Across the street we saw a bear, a lion and a donkey* -- perhaps because that's rather unusual.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I would tend to expect that, yeah, because it's implied that they're in a group and that's weird.  If someone said it without the articles, though, I wouldn't think it was *incorrect*, I would think they were highlighting how odd it was to find those three associating with one another.

Comment: +1 for "This connotation isn't inescapable..."

Comment: Hmm. I would write, "Across the street I saw a man, a woman, and a child." On the other hand, "Every man, woman, and child on the street saw the bear." Or "The bear attacked a man, woman, and child." Maybe. I'm not sure there are clear rules here.

Comment: As an AmE speaker (re @AndrewLeach's comment), I don't know what to make of 'I saw a bear, lion, and donkey.' That is, it doesn't have a coherent meaning  (and doesn't have the one you gave)). I think every article is needed. I don't have enough introspection available to say anything intelligent about why I think that.

Comment: While I wouldn't say that the answer is incorrect, it doesn't meet ELU standards, citing no authoritative evidence.

Comment: Yes, in 2012 it was enough to be right, rather than needing to be right and also jump through argumentum ad verecundiam hoops.