# Repeating "the" with each item separated by "or"

Tags: articles, conjunctions, conjunction-reduction

If we have several items to mention, which should be separated with **or**, is this correct to use **the** for each one? Could it be possible to use one "the" to distribute among them?

For example, which of the following questions is proper?

> When we teach this unit, should we focus on **the** textbook or **the** presentation?

or

> When we teach this unit, should we focus on **the** textbook or presentation?

This question differs from the question put in the topic:
[Is it necessary to use "the" multiple times?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/is-it-necessary-to-use-the-multiple-times), since the separation by the conjunction **or** has not been addressed in this topic.

Comment: Firstly, the definite article belongs to the noun following it and unrelated to the conjunction use: *of the idealism or the materialism* is grammatical and has its uses. However, in the present example, the use of definite article seems incorrect. The concepts are *idealism* and *materialism* -- no *the* before them.

Comment: Please also visit [ell.se]

Comment: The examples have been changed to better clarify the question.

Comment: The articles ***still*** don't sound belong here. It should be *"should we focus on idealism or materialism?"* This is because idealism and materialism are uncountable nouns.

Comment: @Kris: Articles ***do*** distribute: *"the dog and cat"* is just as correct as *"the dog and the cat"*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+dog+and+cat%2C+the+dog+and+the+cat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20dog%20and%20cat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20dog%20and%20the%20cat%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor
An example from LDOCE5:
the idealism of the younger generation

Comment: @Sara Winslet: In that example, you have *"of the younger generation"* after *"idealism"*, which  means you can put *"the"* before it, because now you're talking about a specific instance of idealism.

Comment: @PeterShor: The nouns are changed.

Comment: When you say "presentation" what do you mean?  Presentation of what?  Without the what this is just bad writing that has everyone spinning their wheels.  Also, how is the textbook related to the unit?

Comment: Now that you have a reasonable sentence, I can give you my answer. Yes, you can leave out the second *the*.

Comment: There are "preferred" schemes, but no hard and fast rules.  In particular, even in cases where only one article may be required, the writer may instead choose to repeat it for emphasis.

Comment: @PeterShor Hope by now you have the things clearer. Do they? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The* can be distributed as provided in the second sentence, so that it is used only once. A similar question on Stack Exchange can be found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/is-it-necessary-to-use-the-multiple-times).

Comment: That question asks about *the A **and** the B*. This one asks about *the A **or** the B*. I don't think you can use that question as a reference for this one.

Comment: @PeterShor Why would conjunction reduction apply to only one of the two most common coordinating conjunctions but not the other?

Comment: @tchrist: grammar is weird; it might not. (Although in this case, I believe it does.)

Answer (score 0):

The citation is from Michael Swan **Practical English Usage**.

*When expressions are joined by* and,but,or,*we often leave out repeated articles.

**A knife and (a) fork**

**A knife or (a) fork**

W*hen double expressions are preceded by prepositions, the articles can altogether be dropped.*

**with knife or fork**

Comment: In the third example, the omission of the article is just in case of having more than one noun, right? can't we use "with knife" instead of "with a/the knife"?

Comment: In the case of having a preceding preposition. In the first two examples, the author added (a) in brackets, but in this case nor brackets with article.

Comment: I asked a different question, please read it again

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't quite catch it.

Answer (score -2):

To answer some of the other comments, the articles *do* belong there, consider

"When we teach this unit, should we focus on textbook or presentation?"

since it is a "specific" unit being discussed. If it were a general unit,

"When we teach units, should we focus on textbook or presentation"

would be fine, since both "textbook" and "presentation" are generic. I would argue that the sentence really needs "either" ...

"When we teach this unit, should we focus on either the textbook or the presentation?"

Comment: Adding *either* to that question makes it sound like there's a third alternative ( namely, don't use either one). That doesn't mean the same thing at all.

Comment: Hi, if there were a third alternative, it would be "When we teach this unit, should we focus on either the textbook, the presentation, or alternative X?" Could you explain why you think it sounds is there is a third option? ie How is if different from "would you like either a hot drink, or a cold drink?"

Comment: The way I understand this, if you ask somebody *"would you like to work on **either** the project report **or** the personnel file"*, you are implicitly giving them an option to say *neither one*. Whereas if you leave out the ***either***, you are telling them to pick one or the other.