# "...at the top or bottom" vs "...at the top or the bottom"

Tags: grammaticality, conjunction-reduction

I'm a bit confused about the usage of "the" in a list. Even after [reading this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/is-it-necessary-to-use-the-multiple-times), it's not clear to me which of the following is grammatically correct.

"Is the [object] at the top or bottom?"

"Is the [object] at the top or the bottom?"

Or should "at" be distributed as well? (In which case, it seems clear that "the" should appear twice.)

"Is the [object] at the top or at the bottom?"

Comment: They are all grammatical, and mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: Deletion, or ellipsis, or something like that, that is.

Answer (score 1):

All of the examples are OK as to grammar.

> "Is the [object] at the top or bottom?"

is the most concise.
But this can be taken another step.
If *calculator* is on an ordered list of office equipment, a question might be:

> "Is *calculator* at the top or bottom?"

also concise and correct, without the "the", if it appears on the list as just "calculator".
If , on the list, "one calculator" appears, the the question would be:

> "Is the *the calculator* at the top or bottom?"

or

> "Is *one calculator* at the top or bottom?"

as the "one" is defining, and any reference to it should include the defining as singular.
One will need to make a decision as to how concise the phrasing need be.