# Do I need to include "the" for each item in a text sequence

Tags: lists, omissibility

Can anyone please tell me that which is more appealing:

> • My industrial collaborations at the national and **the** international levels.
>
> • My industrial collaborations at the national and international levels.

What if the list has more than two items, like this:

> Our contributions have impacts on the wireless industry, **the** application of IoT, **the** underwater channels, etc.

Do I need to add **"the"** before each item?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to use "the" multiple times?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/is-it-necessary-to-use-the-multiple-times)

Answer (score 2):

The initial "the" is enough for the entire list.

Exceptions are possible, though, as briefly explained in [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/is-it-necessary-to-use-the-multiple-times) to the same question.